# How to use multiple "like" and "and"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant get this sql query work the way i want to. I am trying to match a record using "like" and "and" but i dont get any result. When i change it to "or" I get the result.

Why do i not get any results when i use and?

```
SELECT   a.MOD_REQ_NUM,
         a.REFERENCE_CODE,
         a.REFERENCE_VALUE,
         a.ACTIVE_DETAIL,
         b.REQUESTOR_WWID,
         b.REQUEST_DATE
 from DB_MOD_REQ_DETAILS a, DB_MOD_REQ_HEADER b
 where a.MOD_REQ_NUM=b.MOD_REQ_NUM
 and a.ACTIVE_DETAIL='Y' 
 and b.ACTIVE_HEADER='Y'
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 and 
    (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2)
 and 
    (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4)
```

---

### This is the screenshot when i use "or"

[image]

---

---

### Update

I want to be able to search the a.REFERENCE_VALUE only in the given a.REFERENCE_CODE. I have got form fields and C# foreach loop. Every field has got its own REFERENCE_CODE. if user is searching for 1 field, i want to do:

```
(a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2)
```

If user is searching more than 1 field, i want to match :

```
a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2
and
a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4
```

this is the screen shot of the query with all the data
[image]

Comment: Because you are asking REFERENCE_VALUE to be like '%43598%' and like'%3694894%', also REFERENCE_CODE  equal to 2 & 4 at a time. How one value can be equal to 2 values?

Comment: Where criteria apply to a single record. So you are saying "return any records WHERE <criteria>" Obviously a single record cant match both of the 2 sub-criteria you put hence why OR is the correct term to use

Comment: You're missing parentheses' in the `or` example - `and ((a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2) or (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4))`.

Comment: You just refuse to listen to what you're being told don't you?  Think about it for a moment.  Boolean logic is not some alien concept.  You use it every day.  If you tried to find all the people in your town whose name contained A and was 24 years old and whose name contained B and was 45 years old, how many people would be on your list?  Zero!  Noone can  be 24 and 45 at the same time.  Likewise, no record in your database can have a code of 2 and a code of 4 at the same time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: emre22 updated her/his question because I asked him to provide some more details about what he wants. I agree that boolean logic is not a concept he handles correctly but I do not think there is a need for you to take it personnally which is what your latest comment reflects.
I have tried to complete your answer which is correct but lacks explanations with regard to this aspect.

Comment: @emre22 thanks for updating your question. I believe what you wrote is not strictly what you want (at least with respect to logic). It is not easy to help as it is less a matter of SQL/coding than it is a problem with your understanding of boolean logic.

Comment: I kind of understand the logic. I think i need to filter the results by adding a nested query or something similar. When i use "or" it doesn`t matter what  REFERENCE_VALUE I search for some fields, i get results when the condition is met by 1 field.

Comment: @emre22 Could you please post the C# code that generates the query?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/g220Jz9p) The codes are not great, i am new to c#. public DataTable GetParamDataSet is where everything is. http://pastebin.com/g220Jz9p

Comment: @emre22 thank you for the code. You should have started with it since the issue is in this piece of software rather than the SQL.
Well, you could say the issue is in your understanding of the logic which is approximate: there is no need for subqueries, only build the correct (wrt boolean logic) SQL statement. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and your comment to jmcilhinney's answer the SQL statement you want is:

```
SELECT   a.MOD_REQ_NUM,
         a.REFERENCE_CODE,
         a.REFERENCE_VALUE,
         a.ACTIVE_DETAIL,
         b.REQUESTOR_WWID,
         b.REQUEST_DATE
FROM DB_MOD_REQ_DETAILS a, DB_MOD_REQ_HEADER b
WHERE a.MOD_REQ_NUM=b.MOD_REQ_NUM
  AND a.ACTIVE_DETAIL='Y' 
  AND b.ACTIVE_HEADER='Y'
----------------------------------------------------------
  AND 
  (
      (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2)
      OR
      (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4)
  )
```

Notice the parentheses to the last clause.

Here is why:

1. Your first statement has AND operators everywhere. This results in having a conjunction of other clauses (`a.MOD_REQ_NUM=b.MOD_REQ_NUM AND a.ACTIVE_DETAIL='Y' AND b.ACTIVE_HEADER='Y' AND a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' AND a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%'`) as well as these:
   `a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4 AND a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2` which is always false. Therefore you will get no result from this SQL statement.
2. Your second statement is close to what you want but not quite it. As Luuan pointed out the parentheses are required: A AND B AND C OR D is not the same as A AND B AND (C OR D). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property for the long explanation.

---

**EDIT:** the piece of software you have provided in a comment to your question is the source of the problem as it does not generate the SQL statement that you need (and which both jmcilhinney and Beatles1692 tried to provide).

**First** replace the following line in GetParamDataSet

```
strCond = " a.REFERENCE_VALUE LIKE'%" + item.Substring(item.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim() + "%'" +
                                " and a.REFERENCE_CODE= " + id;
```

with

```
strCond = " (a.REFERENCE_VALUE LIKE'%" + item.Substring(item.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim() + "%'" +
                                " and a.REFERENCE_CODE= " + id + ")";
```

*Notice the parentheses!*

**Second** replace the main block in `GetDataValue(List<string> conditions)` with

```
string strSQL = "SELECT a.MOD_REQ_NUM, " +
                " a.REFERENCE_CODE, " +
                " a.REFERENCE_VALUE, " +
                " a.ACTIVE_DETAIL, " +
                " b.REQUESTOR_WWID, " +
                " b.REQUEST_DATE " +
                " from DB_MOD_REQ_DETAILS a, DB_MOD_REQ_HEADER b " +
                " where a.MOD_REQ_NUM=b.MOD_REQ_NUM " +
                " and a.ACTIVE_DETAIL='Y' and b.ACTIVE_HEADER='Y' ";

-- construct the conjunction of "(a.REFERENCE_VALUE LIKE '%%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = %)"
string referenceCodeValueCondition = string.Join<string>( " OR ", conditions );

-- append the conjunction block to the other conditions
if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty( referenceCodeValueCondition ))
{
    strSQL = strSQL + " AND (" + referenceCodeValueCondition + ")";
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, I tried to explain what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks alot, it is working perfect. I still need an advice on how to filter the results. At the moment, if 1 field returns with results, it doesn`t matter what ever search keyword you entered for the other fields.

Comment: @emre22 I don't understand what you mean. I think you will have to open a new question with your C# piece of code.

Answer (score 5):

This part doesn't make sense:

```
and 
    (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2)
and 
    (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4)
```

How can `REFERENCE_CODE` ever be 2 and 4?  At the very least, there should be an OR between those last two sets of conditions, i.e.

```
and 
    ((a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2)
or
    (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4))
```

You may or may not need to change other AND operators to OR as well.

Comment: I want to pair "a.REFERENCE_CODE" and "a.REFERENCE_VALUE". If i do this: `and (a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4 or a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2) and (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3%' or a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%0%' )` does it mean `a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3%'` will get searched only in `a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4`

Comment: Please put this information in your initial question and provide precisions on what it is you want: the output is what is expected from the command you have input.

Comment: No. It means that any reults returned will have `a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2` OR `a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2` AND `a.REFERENCE_VALUE` will be like `%3%` OR '%0%'. You need to pay attention to your logical operators and parentheses.

Comment: I updated my question, I tried to explain what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
(a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2) and (a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4)
```

This means that both conditions should be true at the same time which in this scenario (according to your result) is not the case. When you change it to :

```
(a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%43598%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 2) or(a.REFERENCE_VALUE like '%3694894%' and a.REFERENCE_CODE = 4)
```

It means that the whole statement considered to be true if any of these conditions are true and then you can see both of them in your result.
The question is what you really want to do ?